# NSInvocationOperation with return value (BOOL)

Tags: iphone, methods, return-value, nsinvocation

hi i have these invocation operation:

```
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] 
             initWithTarget:ndParser selector:@selector (parseUrl:)
             object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL%@",var]];
```

my method:

```
- (BOOL) parseUrl:(NSString *)URL;
```

should throw back bool....

how can i catch this value?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result like this:

```
BOOL result;
[[operation result] getValue:&result];
```

From the [docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesnt work... should the operation object not local?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you mean by 'should the operation object not local'

Comment: i have the resolution! i had to wait for the procedure, of course... thank you